# Dynamically adding input fields JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to enter two `input` fields and one `button` dynamically adding them from the button `click` function.

They should look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRnDu.png

On click of the button `add`, I would like to disable the button, add a new row of items (2 `input` boxes and the clickable `button` again). I would also like to store the 2 values from the text-boxes in an array.

```
add() { 
    let row = document.createElement('div');   
    row.className = 'row'; 
    row.innerHTML += ` 
    <br> 
    <input type="text" id="text1"> <input type="text" id="text2"> <button id="button">ADD</button> `; 
    document.querySelector('.showInputField').appendChild(row); 
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click',this.input,false);}input(){
        
    let inputValue = (document.getElementById("text1") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    console.log(inputValue);
    this.user.push(inputValue);
    this.users.push(this.user);
    this.user = [];
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div> 
    CLICK ON BUTTON TO ADD NEW FIELD 
    <div class="showInputField">
        <button (click)="add()">ADD</button> 
    </div> 
    <!-- The add() function is called -->
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try? What prevents you to implement this?

Comment: @sjahan my implementation would not help, im just not good enough, i need help

Comment: @sjahan i just posted my try

Comment: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/AXVrV check this example Working demo or dynamic html form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div id="education_fields">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Schoolname" name="Schoolname[]" value=""
                    placeholder="School name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]">

                        <option value="">Date</option>
                        <option value="2015">2015</option>
                        <option value="2016">2016</option>
                        <option value="2017">2017</option>
                        <option value="2018">2018</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="education_fields();"> <span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var room = 1;
    function education_fields() {

        room++;
        var objTo = document.getElementById('education_fields')
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass" + room);
        var rdiv = 'removeclass' + room;
        divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Schoolname" name="Schoolname[]" value="" placeholder="School name"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> <select class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]"><option value="">Date</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option> </select><div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_education_fields(' + room + ');"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';

        objTo.appendChild(divtest)
    }
    function remove_education_fields(rid) {
        $('.removeclass' + rid).remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That is great, but how do i get the values from the text-boxes? I need them in an array

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJ9OO3OR58NA  Here You See working Demo Just copy paste this code and hit ur backend api and check results u can also check ur result in brower console